# Checking Answers Of Dynamically Created Quiz Questions With AJAX & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, logic

This is more of a logic question then a code related question, although it may be the opposite. My brain is fried. I have a script which displays lessons for certain subjects. When a user is done with a lesson they can choose to be quizzed on the subject. The quiz page takes the lesson ID and searches the database for the last 5 questions which match the lesson ID. I then dynamically display these questions on a page within a form. Below are some code examples:

**quiz.app.php**

```
    $lesson = $_GET['id'];
if(!checkRecord('lessons', '*', 'id', $lesson)) {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lesson_questions WHERE lesson_id = ? LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute([$lesson]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = [
        'question_id' => $row['id'],
        'lesson_id' => $row['lesson_id'],
        'question' => clean($row['question']),
        'answer1' => clean($row['answer1']),
        'answer2' => clean($row['answer2']),
        'answer3' => clean($row['answer3']),
        'answer4' => clean($row['answer4']),
        'correct_answer' => clean($row['correct_answer']),
        'question_expl' => clean($row['question_expl'])
    ];
}
```

**quiz.php**

```
                        <form name="quiz" action="quiz.php?id=<?=$lesson?>" method="POST">
                        <?php foreach($result as $question): ?>
                            <div class="question">
                                <h5 class="text-dark"><?=$question['question'];?></h5>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer" id="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer_A" value="answer1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer">
                                        <?=$question['answer1']?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer" id="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer_B" value="answer2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer">
                                        <?=$question['answer2']?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer" id="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer_C" value="answer3">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer">
                                        <?=$question['answer3']?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer" id="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer_D" value="answer4">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="question_<?=$question['question_id']?>_answer">
                                        <?=$question['answer4']?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$_SESSION['token']?>" />
                        <a href="lesson.php?id=<?=$lesson?>" class="btn btn-md"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back to lesson</a>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit_quiz" class="btn btn-md btn-success float-end">Submit Quiz</button>
```

My plan is to take the users answer to each question and send it off to a file to process VIA AJAX. However, my brain cannot comprehend how I would reference each question individually to check the answer. I've tried using a hidden field to store the question ID with something like name="question_id[]" but I either recieve an error with jQuery or only get the last questions ID displayed. If anyone has a fresh brain and could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Comment: From my work experience doing a highly similar project : You should trigger an ajax call to update and check the answer of the question for EACH question when the radio button is clicked and then update the db.

Comment: You could name each question input something like `name="questions[<?=$question['question_id']?>]"` then on the server iterate over it with `<?php foreach($_POST['questions'] as $questionID=>$answer)...`